# What are the limitations of Peter Singer's utilitarianism?

Tags: ethics, utilitarianism, singer

What are the limitations of Singer's argument in "Famine, Affluence and Morality" and the conclusion he presents ?
As well as the limitations of his statement that letting the child drown when you are fully capable of saving him is the same as not sending money to help someone overseas.
Concentration on moral responsibility and difference in preception of local emergencies and cases of famine.

Comment: Hello, mara kozelets, welcome to PSE. Just a query: 'preception' ? I hesitate to alter this since you might mean 'perception' or 'prescription' - or something else. 'Preception' is an Anglicised term in Roman Law, so you may mean 'preception' after all.  Best - Geoffrey

Comment: Hello, Geoffrey Thomas, a spelling mistake has been made, I meant to say 'perception', specifying of the difference between how people view the cases of local emergencies and cases of famine.